# AWS access/secret keys for Amazon Simple AD users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have setup Amazon Simple AD and assigned specific roles to AD users that enable them to get access to the AWS console. I am trying to find a way where i can give same user programmatic access to AWS resources. Basically how can get these simple AD users a access key & secret key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Simple AD Users are not AWS IAM Users. That's the distinction. Only IAM Users can get keys with which to access the AWS API.

There is an exception to the above statement - if you set up a federated identity provider in IAM. There are many supported federated identity providers that use SAML (OIDC works too), but since you already have a Simple AD, you might as well use ADFS. It's a bit of a pain to set up but AWS recently released a premade CloudFormation template specifically to deploy ADFS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/wap-adfs/welcome.html

Once you have ADFS set up and mapped to your AD users...they still can't get access keys for the API!...but they can use federated auth to authenticate as themselves with AWS APIs:

PowerShell (the useful part is more than halfway down): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/saml-pst.html

Linux CLI: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-implement-federated-api-and-cli-access-using-saml-2-0-and-ad-fs/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use key pairs (access key and secret key) to log into the AWS console (UI). You can create users and generate password for that purpose (those are different than key pairs). My understanding is key pairs are used for programmatic purposes only, you can use them for SDKs, AWS APIs and AWS CLI.

To allow AD users (and passwords) to log into the AWS console, you'll have to implement/enable Federation but it's not as simple as you may think. I found this guide, hope it helps!
[Enabling Federation to AWS Using Windows Active Directory, ADFS, and SAML 2.0](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/enabling-federation-to-aws-using-windows-active-directory-adfs-and-saml-2-0/)